NextJS Site fetching different content in live version with GraphQL
I have developed a NextJS site with a headless CraftCMS backend and deployed through Vercel. (Since the site is live I have translated the items now for the time being but it's still fetching from the wrong language)
I am fetching my content using Apollo and Graphql.
The problem is now that for whatever reason on the live site I get different content, specifically the menuItem's language is wrong even though the rest of the query gets me the right language.
What could be the problem?


my query:
query MyQuery($language: [String]) {
globalSets(language: $language) {
  ... on footer_GlobalSet {
    footerJobLinkLabel
    footerSection1
    footerSection2
    footerSection3
    footerSocials {
      ... on socialMediaChannel_Entry {
        socialMediaUrl
        icon { 
          url
          width
          height
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ... on general_GlobalSet {
    reserveActive
    languageSwitcherActive
    reserveLabel
    deliveryLabel
    applyLabel
    hoursLabel
    kitchenLabel
    allLocationsLabel
    moreLabel
    downloadText
    menuItems {
      ... on menuItem_Entry {
        id
        label
        pageRelation
        inputLink
        menuSubItems {
          ... on menuSubItem_Entry {
            id
            label
            pageRelation
            inputLink
          }
        }
      }
    }
    firstNameLabel
    lastNameLabel
    mailLabel
    numberLabel
    notesLabel
    sendLabel
    uploadLabel
    uploadInfo
    jobLabel
  }
}

}
And my Fetch:
const globalData = await apolloClient.query({
  query: GLOBAL_QUERY(),
  variables: {
    language: locale.locale
  }

});
